# Display an element value in html

Tags: javascript, html

If i have an html element

```
<input id="name" type="text" value="sam" />
```

is it possible to display the value other than in the text box? like

```
<label>Your name is '#name'</label>
```

I know the above is wrong,hope you get the question

Comment: this can be done using javascript.

Comment: How , can u suggest a method?

Comment: So you wanted to show the name into your label on every key press?

Comment: @user34305 did you search how to do this? did you find anything? Did you face any problem implementing them?

Answer (score 3):

```
label.html($('#name').attr('value'));
```

Using `html()` to insert content into the element `label` and `attr()` is used to find the value of a function.

You can't use only HTML. If you don't know, you'd need to include the jQuery file and put this code in the `<script>` tags.

**Javascript Alternative**

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('myLabel').innerHTML= document.getElementById("name").getAttribute("value");
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery is a bit bulky for this

Comment: Yeah,any direct method in html?

Comment: No, you don't have an function for that.

Comment: EDIT, using pure JS instead.

Comment: NO, there is no direct method because HTML is just a markup language. Simply place the <script> block in your code, and you'd get the required results.